# Querying in HIVE hadoop with \ (Back slash)

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I need to query on the column which is having values like this

Column name is locations:

```
c:\users\abcd\hello
c:\users\xyabcddd\hello
c:\users\abcder\hello
```

I need to query the value 'abcd' exactly

```
select * from table where locations like '%\abcd\'
select * from table where locations like '%\\abcd\\'
select * from table where locations like '%\\\\abcd\\\\'
```

Above all are not working.

If I query like below

```
select * 
from table 
where locations like '%abcd%'
```

it will fetch all the results, not the exact one

```
c:\users\abcd\hello
c:\users\xyabcddd\hello
c:\users\abcder\hello
```

but I need

Exactly this one 'c:\users\abcd\hello'

Comment: With regex you can match like this `.*\\abcd\\.*` and you will get exactly the column with `\abcd\\` in it.

Comment: If you want exactly that value, then why are you using a wildcard on both sides of the string with only abcd?

Comment: please provide the exact query.

Comment: @cricket_007: Because OP wants to select whole column name having `\abcd\\` in it. Wildcard on both sides will capture everything on both sides of `\abcd\\`.

Comment: @noob I know what a wildcard does, but OP wants "exact", not LIKE

Comment: @cricket_007: I think you are not getting me. It will get "exactly" the column having `\abcd\\` in it.

Comment: @noob Okay, I see what you are saying, but I assumed OP wanted the exact string including the "c:\users" piece, not all paths with "abcd" as a directory

Comment: regex is fine. but how to use regex in HIVE queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

```
select locations from tablename where 
(instr(lower(locations),'\\abcd\\') IS NOT NULL) 
AND (instr(lower(locations),'\\abcd\\') != 0)
```

This will fetch only

```
c:\users\abcd\hello
```

ref: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions